# Got error 28 from storage engine

Tags: codeigniter, storage-engines

My website used CodeIgnter framework and host with iPage. Before, my PHP version is 5.2, then i update it to 5.3. After i updated to PHP 5.3 always get error as below:

```
- Got error 28 from storage engine
- Incorrect key file for table '/mysql-tmp/#sql_16c4_0.MYI'. try to repair it
- Got error -1 from storage engine
```

It's not a new question in StackOverflow, but I want to make sure that:

- Does these error cause from my update from PHP 5.2 to 5.3?
- Does it cause from my misconfiguration in php.ini?
- From hosting? or any others?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a disk space issue:

[MySQL: #126 - Incorrect key file for table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011050/mysql-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table)

Contact your hosting provider.

Also, this is a mysql issue, not a PHP issue; doesn't matter what version of php you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Got error 28 from storage engine

Disk space problem..

Need space to save the data in the database
if it is loaclhost check your drive memory status if memory is full in that disk free some space.

if it is hosting contact your hosting  provider