# Mysql replication error

Tags: mysql

I am receiving an error in mysql while checking the status

```
mysql>SHOW MYSQL STATUS\G;

Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Incorrect key file for table './aaa_bbb/abcd_xxyyzz.MYI';
try to repair it' on query. Default database: 'aaa_bbb'.
Query: 'UPDATE abcd_xxyyzz SET abcd_xxyyzz = 12345678912, abcd_xxyyzz = 'posting.php?mode=reply&f=23&t=156&confirm_key=4DGHJNBFTH', abcd_xxyyzz_id = 11 WHERE abcd_xxyyzz_id='2dfggrehtrhfdfvsdasdsas2fsd1fdf45'
```

Could anybody helps to resolve the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011050/mysql-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table

Comment: Well, have you tried to [repair it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html)?

Comment: Resolved the Issue by reparing the table :)

mysql> use aaa_bbb
mysql> repair table abcd_xxyyzz;
mysql> slave stop;
mysql> slave start;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can resolve this Issue by repairing the table. In the mysql command prompt:

```
mysql -u username -p password
mysql> use aaa_bbb;
mysql> repair table abcd_xxyyzz;
mysql> slave stop;
mysql> slave start;
```