# Mysql incorrect key file for table (on indexed tables)

Tags: mysql, file, key

In a mysql database located on a server, I do a backup every day, compressing the folder of the database, located in "C: \ xampp \ mysql \ data". I usually decompress the database on my local machine, for development and testing. I never had a problem doing this.

Until yesterday I had to index some tables, because queries were very slow.
Then when I unzip the folder on my local machine, I explore the database with Navicat, and when I try to open any of the indexed tables, I'm getting this error:

> "incorrect key file for table".

Already tried using "repair" without good results. Could anyone help?

Comment: It's not a problem with Navicat,since neither my system can not open tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: #126 - Incorrect key file for table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011050/mysql-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table)

Answer (score 0):

make your backups with sql dump rather then directly copying data files. it will prevent you such as problems generally... but importing from dump could be longer if you have too many records in your tables.

Comment: I imagined it, the problem is that I have many tables and large. the system used in a hospital. Currently I do a backup every 3 hours with cobian.

Comment: isn't it possible to dump data to somewhere, then make backup of dump ?... it's really not a good way, there could be other "silent" problems cause of this behaviour...

Comment: not impossible, but the way it was, I did not have to do anything, the cobian did everything for me. because I do not come to the hospital every day.

Comment: so... are you using same mysql version for production and test environment, or maybe there is a problem with todays zip file, try yesterdays data and see same thing happens... [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,362974,363291#msg-363291) is a suggestion, maybe you can try this.