# MySQL error, database duplicates

Tags: mysql

I manage a recruitment website that has been built using Perch (grabaperch.com) a simple php content management system.

I have a bit of an odd issue, and not being a mysql expert - i'm not sure how to resolve. Every now and again, the database seems to massively bloat - and the site falls over. When I take a look at the actual DB, it looks as though the jobs have replicated themselves.

There's a lot of weird stuff going on in the mysql error log - I've pasted a snippet below - I'm hoping someone can give me an idea of what may be going wrong.

```
140805  8:28:38 [Warning] IP address '218.15.203.72' has been resolved to the host name '72.203.15.218.broad.yf.gd.dynamic.163data.com.cn', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
140805  8:43:03 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_34dc_46.MYI'; try to repair it
140805  8:43:03 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.37/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
140805  8:43:03 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_34dc_21.MYI'; try to repair it
140805  8:43:03 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.37/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
140805  8:43:03 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_34dc_2.MYI'; try to repair it
140805  8:43:03 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.37/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
140805  8:43:03 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_34dc_27.MYI'; try to repair it
140805  8:43:03 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.37/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
140805  8:43:03 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_34dc_49.MYI'; try to repair it
```

This repeats quite a few times.

I also see a lot of the following in the log...

```
---TRANSACTION 896F, not started flushing log
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
MySQL thread id 664483, OS thread handle 0x7ffde480c700, query id 20002663 localhost formuser query end
UPDATE `form`.`user` SET sessiontoken = '53dfe99a2d7537.42615665', sessiontimestamp=NOW() WHERE username = '1961kjm@gmail.com'
```

I've tried repairing the table, but it doesn't make much difference.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011050/mysql-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003106/mysql-error-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Nope, plenty of free space available.