# Redmine 2.4.3 error occurred while executing the query (incorrect key file table)

Tags: mysql, redmine, bitnami

I'm currently getting this error when trying to view issues for just one particular project.

> An error occurred while executing the query and has been logged. Please report this error to your Redmine administrator.

Other users are not getting this issue on the same project.

When I look in the logs I get this error

```
    App 31192 stderr: Query::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect key file for table '/opt/redmine/mysql/tmp/#sql_f5c_0.MYI'; try to repair it:

    SELECT  `issues`.`id` AS t0_r0, `issues`.`tracker_id` AS t0_r1, `issues`.`project_id` AS t0_r2, `issues`.`subject` 
    AS t0_r3, `issues`.`description` AS t0_r4, `issues`.`due_date` AS t0_r5, `issues`.`category_id` 
    AS t0_r6, `issues`.`status_id` AS t0_r7, `issues`.`assigned_to_id` AS t0_r8, `issues`.`priority_id` 
    AS t0_r9, `issues`.`fixed_version_id` AS t0_r10, `issues`.`author_id` AS t0_r11, `issues`.`lock_version` 
    AS t0_r12, `issues`.`created_on` AS t0_r13, `issues`.`updated_on` AS t0_r14, `issues`.`start_date` 
    AS t0_r15, `issues`.`done_ratio` AS t0_r16, `issues`.`estimated_hours` AS t0_r17, `issues`.`parent_id` 
    AS t0_r18, `issues`.`root_id` AS t0_r19, `issues`.`lft` AS t0_r20, `issues`.`rgt` AS t0_r21, `issues`.`is_private` 
    AS t0_r22, `issues`.`closed_on` AS t0_r23, `projects`.`id` AS t1_r0, `projects`.`name` 
    AS t1_r1, `projects`.`description` AS t1_r2, `projects`.`homepage` AS t1_r3, `projects`.`is_public` 
    AS t1_r4, `projects`.`parent_id` AS t1_r5, `projects`.`created_on` AS t1_r6, `projects`.`updated_on` 
    AS t1_r7, `projects`.`identifier` AS t1_r8, `projects`.`status` AS t1_r9, `projects`.`lft` 
    AS t1_r10, `projects`.`rgt` AS t1_r11, `projects`.`inherit_members` AS t1_r12, `issue_statuses`.`id` 
    AS t2_r0, `issue_statuses`.`name` AS t2_r1, `issue_statuses`.`is_closed` AS t2_r2, `issue_statuses`.`is_default` 
    AS t2_r3, `issue_statuses`.`position` AS t2_r4, `issue_statuses`.`default_done_ratio` AS t2_r5, `users`.`id` 
    AS t3_r0, `users`.`login` AS t3_r1, `users`.`hashed_password` AS t3_r2, `users`.`firstname` 
    AS t3_r3, `users`.`lastname` AS t3_r4, `users`.`mail` AS t3_r5, `users`.`admin` AS t3_r6, `users`.`status` 
    AS t3_r7, `users`.`last_login_on` AS t3_r8, `users`.`language` AS t3_r9, `users`.`auth_source_id` 
    AS t3_r10, `users`.`created_on` AS t3_r11, `users`.`updated_on` AS t3_r12, `users`.`type` 
    AS t3_r13, `users`.`identity_url` AS t3_r14, `users`.`mail_notification` AS t3_r15, `users`.`salt` 
    AS t3_r16, `users`.`must_change_passwd` AS t3_r17, `trackers`.`id` AS t4_r0, `trackers`.`name` 
    AS t4_r1, `trackers`.`is_in_chlog` AS t4_r2, `trackers`.`position` AS t4_r3, `trackers`.`is_in_roadmap` 
    AS t4_r4, `trackers`.`fields_bits` AS t4_r5, `enumerations`.`id` AS t5_r0, `enumerations`.`name` 
    AS t5_r1, `enumerations`.`position` AS t5_r2, `enumerations`.`is_default` AS t5_r3, `enumerations`.`type` 
    AS t5_r4, `enumerations`.`active` AS t5_r5, `enumerations`.`project_id` AS t5_r6, `enumerations`.`parent_id` 
    AS t5_r7, `enumerations`.`position_name` AS t5_r8, `issue_categories`.`id` AS t6_r0, `issue_categories`.`project_id` 
    AS t6_r1, `issue_categories`.`name` AS t6_r2, `issue_categories`.`assigned_to_id` AS t6_r3, `versions`.`id` 
    AS t7_r0, `versions`.`project_id` AS t7_r1, `versions`.`name` AS t7_r2, `versions`.`description` 
    AS t7_r3, `versions`.`effective_date` AS t7_r4, `versions`.`created_on` AS t7_r5, `versions`.`updated_on` 
    AS t7_r6, `versions`.`wiki_page_title` AS t7_r7, `versions`.`status` AS t7_r8, `versions`.`sharing` AS t7_r9 
    FROM `issues` 
    INNER JOIN `issue_statuses` ON `issue_statuses`.`id` = `issues`.`status_id` 
    INNER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `issues`.`project_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `issues`.`assigned_to_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `trackers` ON `trackers`.`id` = `issues`.`tracker_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `enumerations` ON `enumerations`.`id` = `issues`.`priority_id` AND `enumerations`.`type` IN ('IssuePriority') 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `issue_categories` ON `issue_categories`.`id` = `issues`.`category_id` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `versions` ON `versions`.`id` = `issues`.`fixed_version_id` 
    WHERE (projects.status  9 AND projects.id IN (SELECT em.project_id 
    FROM enabled_modules em WHERE em.name='issue_tracking'))
     AND ((issues.status_id IN (SELECT id FROM issue_statuses WHERE is_closed=0)) 
    AND projects.id IN (205,145,24,67,151,186,177,179,178,7,162,62,216,64,232,60,225,98,190,170,100,188,101,
    223,99,126,207,208,237,214,58,118,120,85,121,54,56,55,117,61,171,66,219,59,15,135,136,130,143,150,144,65,63,
    22,74,84,191,41,175,21,231,42,49,131,134,133,193,166,174,148,124,11,192,181,212,209,210,250,211,182,187,164,
    228,26,19,75,70,71,141,152,159,142,86,87,88,108,91,92,146,147,138,139,140,156,158,157,102,104,105,107,106,103,
    127,132,129,128,69,153,68,17,176,113,220,116,112,110,111,227,217,218,203,204,201,25,73,172,160,161,3,35,36,37,
    247,248,249,38,5,83,82,169,168,167,81,53,27,77,14,2,189,78,13,245,221,206,40,76,184,79,185,33,137,80,222,246,28,
    226,29,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,31,47,32,163,251,230,57,165,224,197,198,233,199,234,235,236,23,89,43,90,213,
    173,44,45,52,46,119,10,97,96,125,93,94,95)) 
    ORDER BY issues.id DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

Redmine details:

```
    Environment:
      Redmine version                2.4.3.stable
      Ruby version                   1.9.3-p484 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
      Rails version                  3.2.16
      Environment                    production
      Database adapter               Mysql2
    SCM:
      Subversion                     1.8.5
      Git                            1.8.5.2
      Filesystem                     
    Redmine plugins:
      redmine_agile                  1.1.0-light
      redmine_contacts               3.2.15-light
      redmine_graphs                 0.1.0
      redmine_issue_checklist        2.0.5
      redmine_work_time              0.2.14
```

I would really appreciate ANY help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a redmine issue. Check if you have enough free space on /opt/redmine/mysql/tmp/

Comment: Thanks @javiferrer, that was the issue, and the reason it was only affecting me was that I am related/linked to more projects, issues, and groups than anyone else.

The select was creating a temp table in the bitnami configured tmp location and this mount point/drive had run out of space.

For anyone else having this issue I hope this helps, you can also have a look at this link: [MySQL, Error 126: Incorrect key file for table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003106/mysql-error-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table)