# MySQL: Slow avg query for 411M rows

Tags: mysql, sql, average, database-performance

I have a simple table (created by django) - engine InnoDB:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| correlation | double           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gene1_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| gene2_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The table has more than **411 million rows**.
(The target table will have around 461M rows, 21471*21470 rows)

My main query looks like this, there might be up to 10 genes specified at most.

```
 SELECT gene1_id, AVG(correlation) AS avg FROM genescorrelation 
 WHERE gene2_id IN (176829, 176519, 176230) 
 GROUP BY gene1_id ORDER BY NULL
```

This query is very slow, it takes almost 2 mins to run:

```
21471 rows in set (1 min 11.03 sec)
```

Indexes (cardinality looks strange - too small?):

```
  Non_unique| Key_name                                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality |
          0 | PRIMARY                                          |            1 | id          | A         |   411512194 | 
          1 | c_gene1_id_6b1d81605661118_fk_genes_gene_entrez  |            1 | gene1_id    | A         |          18 |
          1 | c_gene2_id_2d0044eaa6fd8c0f_fk_genes_gene_entrez |            1 | gene2_id    | A         |          18 |
```

I just run select count(*) on that table and it took 22 mins:

```
select count(*) from predictions_genescorrelation;

+-----------+
| count(*)  |
+-----------+
| 411512002 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (22 min 45.05 sec)
```

What could be wrong?
I suspect that mysql configuration is not set up right.

During the import of data I experienced problem with space, so that might also affected the database, although I ran `check table`  later - it took 2hours and stated OK.

Additionally - the cardinality of the indexes look strange. I have set up smaller database locally and there values are totally different (254945589,56528,17).

Should I redo indexes? 
What params should I check of MySQL?
My tables are set up as InnoDB, would MyISAM make any difference?

Thanks,
matali

Comment: I think that this question would be better suitable on http://dba.stackexchange.com since it involves more configuration than query performance.

Comment: For a query like this I would create an index `(gene2_id, gene1_id, correlation)`. Additionally the  `id` serial might be totally useless, do you ever use it in WHERE-conditions? And what's your logical Primary Key,  `(gene2_id, gene1_id)`?

Comment: Do you need `id`?  It seems like `PRIMARY KEY(gene2_id, gene1_id)` would be unique, and much faster.  Also, the gene_ids could be `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` to be 2 bytes instead of the current 2 bytes.

Comment: Stay with InnoDB.  But check `innodb_buffer_pool_size`; it should be about 70% of RAM.  It would be especially good if it were bigger than the table size.

Comment: The logic for putting this on hold is bogus.  It's an optimization question for which there are many answers, most of them orthogonal and additive.

Comment: Thanks for hints. I am going to ask to increase innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/

`SELECT COUNT(*)` queries are very slow without `WHERE` clause or without `SELECT COUNT(id)` ... `USE INDEX (PRIMARY)`.

to speedup this:

```
 SELECT gene1_id, AVG(correlation) AS avg FROM genescorrelation 
 WHERE gene2_id IN (176829, 176519, 176230) 
 GROUP BY gene1_id ORDER BY NULL
```

you should have composite key on (gene2_id, gene1_id, correlation) in that order. try

About index-cardinality: stats of Innodb tables are approximate, not accurate (sometimes insane). there even was (IS?) a bug-report https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58382

Try to ANALIZE table and watch cardinality again

Comment: Thanks! Cardinality changed to 411512194, 95522, 95522. Now working on index.

Comment: it will not be fast)) working on index. try gene2_id, gene1_id. not 3 parts

Comment: yea. if not helps then gene2_id, gene1_id, correlation

Comment: When creating an index I ran into: ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table 'predictions_genescorrelation'; try to repair it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003106/mysql-error-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table