# MySQL Error Incorrect key file. myisamchk repair works but table corrupts again soon

Tags: mysql, myisam

my first question on stackoverflow so I hope I have followed all the guidelines.

I have a website with MySql db on a Digital Ocean droplet.

I found mysql had stopped running and after looking found corrupt tables. After repairing them with `myisamchk -r` I thought the problem was solved. However it kept occurring. I changed `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20M in my.cnf` and a have created some free space on `/dev/vda/` after reading this [MySQL, Error 126: Incorrect key file for table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003106/mysql-error-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table)

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              239664        4    239660   1% /dev
tmpfs              50176      380     49796   1% /run
/dev/vda1       20511356 12346408   7099992  64% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              250872        0    250872   0% /run/shm
```

I have these errors in the mysql/error.log

```
[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './websitename/wp_options.MYI'; try to repair it
[ERROR] Got an error from thread_id=178, /build/mysql-5.5-heGK82/mysql-5.5-5.5.55/storage/myisam/mi_update.c:226
[ERROR] MySQL thread id 178, OS thread handle 0x7f4544010700, query id 69124 localhost th3489075 Updating
```

When I run `myisamchk db_name.MYI` on the corrupt table I get

```
Checking MyISAM file: wp_options.MYI
Data records:     375   Deleted blocks:       0
myisamchk: warning: Table is marked as crashed
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
- check file-size    
myisamchk: error: Size of datafile is: 1059228           Should be: 1059276
- check record delete-chain
- check key delete-chain
- check index reference
- check data record references index: 1
- check data record references index: 2
- check record links
myisamchk: error: Keypointers and record positions doesn't match
myisamchk: warning: Found        375 key parts. Should be: 377
MyISAM-table 'wp_options.MYI' is corrupted
Fix it using switch "-r" or "-o"
```

Repairing the table with `myisamchk -r or -o` options seems to work as running `myisamchk *.MYI` immediately after reports no problems but later on it returns the error above.

I have various backups of the db but am unsure how different they are from the current ones.

I understand the warning `myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly` occurs if mysql is running.

When mysql is stopped `myisamchk *.MYI` reports all ok but mysql still crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Every time there is a power failure or other abrupt termination of mysqld, MyISAM tables *may* be corrupted.  This is a strong reason to switch to InnoDB, which does a better job of protecting itself and automatically repair upon restart.

Meanwhile, you could *try* `OPTIMIZE TABLE` as a way of forcing a rebuild of the table.  This may or may not lose the data that seems to be missing, but it will *probably* get rid of the error message until the next crash.

Comment: Thanks Rick, yes I hear Innodb is more robust, something to bear in mind for the future. Was chatting to a mate today and he suggested dumping the database and importing it. So far this is running with no errors. I'll also bear in mind the OPTIMIZE TABLE method.