# getting '#126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_473_3.MYI'; try to repair it' error in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am running a mysql query,which after sometime gives me following error:

```
#126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_473_3.MYI'; try to repair it
```

**what the above error mean exactly and what are the possible reasons which lead to this error?**

Comment: read this question's answer I think this will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011050/mysql-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have filled your /tmp partition. When you run a query involving more than one JOIN mysql stores some temporary data in /tmp.

If disk space in /tmp partition is not sufficient, mysql gives that (IMHO misleading) error.

Answer (score -1):

Check if there were no space left on device, cause this create 1MB /tmp partition.

```
lsof | grep tmp
```

check what use /tmp, and stop the service

```
service mysql stop
service vmware-tools stop
```

then `umount /tmp` and start services. 
It should be fine.