# MySQL error 126: incorrect keyfile or table

Tags: php, mysql, virtualbox

I am using Fedora20 64 bit on virtualbox.  I install partkeepr on PHP.  I get this error How I fix it?

```
**SQLSTATE(HY000) General error 126:incorrect keyfile or table.  Tmp/#sql_9fb_0.MYI**
```

Comment: restart the mysql server !!

Comment: I restart but error change SQLSTATE(HY000) General error 126:incorrect keyfile or table. **Tmp/#sql_866_0.MYI**

Comment: hmm looks like either tables are corrupted or tmp folder does not have more space. If corrupted then u can use `repair `tablename` quick`. If it does not solve then u may need to assign more space to tmp folder  check here http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=32629

Comment: I need some help to increase virtual disk capacity. My disk is fill. My disk tip is VMDK and I use virtualbox

Comment: Hmm I even dont know how to do on VMDK u may check here https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=10348

Comment: Thanks Abhik I increase my disk. But error changed: General error 126: tmp/#sql_4e4_0.MYI

Comment: So still having issue ? if so try this repair table_name quick for all the tables that u may have

Comment: I Repair all tables but still same error **general error 126: tmp/sql_4e4_0.MYI**

Comment: check this thread it might help u on how to reset the tmp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011050/mysql-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table