# Can't create a user on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am typing the following into the command prompt:

```
GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'jim'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
```

I keep getting

> ERROR 126: Incorrect key file for table. .\mysql\dbi.MYI': try to
>   repair it.

How do I repair dbi.MYI? I read somewhere that my *tmp* folder might be too small? If that's the case how do I increase the size?

Comment: Have you tried running repair table? [REPAIR TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html)

Comment: I tried REPAIR TABLE db.myi, and it said '"db.myi' doesn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: #126 - Incorrect key file for table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011050/mysql-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table)

Comment: You ran `repair table db;`?

Comment: Just tried that, and I got 'publications.db' doesn't exist.

Comment: You may need to log in as root and then `use mysql;` first.

Comment: Still not working =(