# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO with PHP and a great table with around 200k values and around 10 columns. It's been 2 months since I have been getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table
```

I have tried every possible method on internet available, including the repair table, repair tmp tables, clearing the tmp cache, changing tmp directory but I am still getting this error and been itching me. If anyone have a solution for this, kindly help.

PS: It only happens when `selecting` the data, not with updating, inserting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011050/mysql-126-incorrect-key-file-for-table please look into this

Comment: Yes, already read and tried all the methods. Disk is fine, tmp thing tried too but still it comes. It comes 1 in 5 run :(

Comment: show your select query and tell how much rows have table and size of db